# What is the optimal number of iterations for jsprit solution for pickups_and_deliveries_solomon_c101.xml?

Tags: jsprit

`VehicleRoutingAlgorithm vra = vraBuilder.build(); 
vra.setMaxIterations(250);`

We use the above code for number of iterations to be done to find vra solution.
in the examples in jsprit I can see 250 as a hard coded value.
My question is what is the optimal value for that.
Is there any option to have solution in between the execution? I don't want to wait 250 number of iterations. Is that possible?

Comment: "what is the optimal value for that?" is an impossible question to answer, it depends entirely on the complexity of your problem. You can change iteration number with `setMaxIterations`. You should also add a listener e.g. `AlgorithmSearchProgressChartListener` and see how many iterations it takes before the solution does not improve. Over time that will give you an idea of the "optimal" for problems of your scale.

Comment: Thanks @roganjosh. When I asked that question I was very new to this. Now I can understand that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your problem size. My suggestion is to set a reasonable large maxIterations and define add termination criterion to the algorithm.

The configuration below terminates the algorithm prematurely based on iterations without any improvement.

```
VehicleRoutingAlgorithm vra = vraBuilder.build(); 
vra.setMaxIterations(250);
vra.addTerminationCriterion(new IterationWithoutImprovementTermination(500));
```

Comment: Thanks @Stanley. I got the answer earlier from the Roganjosh.